# Web app using embedded Tomcat only works in IDE

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, embedded-tomcat-8

I recently switched a large project from Spring MVC to Spring Boot and i'm facing issues running the resulting JAR file (with dependencies inside) outside of Netbeans.  Here is the POM.XML file which works perfectly when run from Netbeans.  Notice the section in comments, i'll get to that in a minute.  Also note that MDHIS_Common has Spring Boot as its parent which makes this a Spring Boot project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>MDHIS_WebClient</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>MDHIS_WebClient</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSTL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--TOMCAT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JASPER REPORTS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SIGAR-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOG4J2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MDHIS_COMMON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
        <artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--TRYING TO WORK AROUND THE EXCEPTIONS
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

When running the resulting JAR outside of Netbeans, i get a series of exceptions which i have detailed in another post which resulted in a quite unpleasant wall of text and was downvoted to oblivion.  Long story short, each dependency was added one at a time to progress through the exceptions i was getting when running the JAR.  With all of those uncommented, the app starts fine but i get this exception the moment i browse to any page :

```
[WEBCLIENT] [ERROR] [2018-08-28 08:22:02.924] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[jsp]                    : Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl.<clinit>(ELContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1234)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:882)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1544)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2389)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2441)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2447)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2389)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1856)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:224)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:383)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.mdenis.mdhis_webclient.filter.PermissionsFilter.doFilter(PermissionsFilter.java:788)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Not sure why the behavior in the IDE vs outside can be so drastically different but there you go.  I searched far and wide for a solution to this and came up empty handed.

***EDIT***

Note that, prior to switching to Spring Boot, i was running Spring MVC with a normal standalone Tomcat 9 install and it worked perfectly.  Only when switching to Spring Boot and Tomcat embedded did I start to experience this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY, i have something that works.  Here is the working dependency list, this works both in Netbeans and using the embedded Tomcat container inside the JAR :

```
<dependencies>

    <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--GLASSFISH-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--TOMCAT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--JASPER REPORTS-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SIGAR-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOG4J2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--MDHIS_COMMON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
        <artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--YASSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details on your project dependencies ? i dont' see any spring boot dependecies except the plugin, what version is being used ?, after configuring spring boot dependencies add this property to pom.xml which the class with @SpringBootApplication annotation :

```
<start-class>ae.gov.sdg.paperless.services.journey.Application</start-class>
```

and from command line try running this command on your project rootdirectory :

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

Comment: This project does not have a parent, MDHIS_Common (which you will find in the dependencies) does :

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

Comment: Also, it finds the main method without issue since the app actually compiles and runs.  Only when i browse to it is the exception thrown.  Everything works perfectly in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Add your project as a sub-maven module and put spring-boot dependecies in that parent instead of _common dependencies, and in your application use  to reference your parent project, checkout my github repository/develop branch : https://github.com/iabughosh/microservices

You will find it very helpful for your case.

Regards,

Comment: I'm sorry i'm still a bit of a newbie with Maven.  Currently the spring dependencies and the parent declaration are in the Common project.  There is also a service project which uses this common project in the same way and everything works fine.  I'm not familiar with modules so i'm having a hard time understanding what you are suggesting.  Are you saying to put the Spring Boot dependencies in the WebClient POM and use Common as a submodule?  I'm doing it this way to repeat as little dependencies as possible and i feel putting the spring boot dependencies in both projects would be undoing that

Comment: Check this out, it will be very helpful for you : https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: Thank you!  One thing i'm getting is that both "children" projects should have the parent declaration and not just the library.  Could that have any impact on my issue with Tomcat only working correctly from within the IDE?

Comment: It should work fine for you, the sample that i've shared with you on my github is running through IDE and command line, Most IDE's understands thats you are working with Maven reactor project, so it should be fine.